# PL/SQL open cursor for query string with varchar2 array

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to use a array in `open c1 for sql-statement` (in plsql)

array is table of `varchar2;`.

array is filled by another function:

```
OPEN v_c1 FOR query_statement;
            LOOP
                v_hrc_list.extend; 
                FETCH v_c1 into v_hrc_list(v_hrc_list.count);
                EXIT WHEN (v_c1%NOTFOUND);
            END LOOP;
        CLOSE v_c1;
```

I tried:

```
query_statement = `...||'WHERE MEMBER OF (select * from table (:table_hrcs))'`

OPEN v_c1 FOR query_statement USING table_hrcs;
```

and I got the following error:

> Inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got CHAR

I also tried

```
...||'WHERE MEMBER OF (select * from table ('||table_hrcs||'))'
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible example (minimized query_statement), ideally as db fiddle. At first sight there seems to be syntax error `where SOMETHING member of ...`. Also specify Oracle version. Also the ora code of error - is it ORA-00932?

Comment: its not executable but: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/X6AzcifZR5J2q9Jt2vzXV/0

yes its ORA-00932

this example (without bind-var): ORA-06550: line 17, column 17:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'

Comment: now i addded the working and non working example (open v_c1 for ...)

Comment: db-fiddle-com doesn't appear to support Oracle. I recommend https://dbfiddle.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up two ways of referring to members of a collection.

With the collection type you appear to have you can either do:

```
' ... WHERE your_column IN (select * from table (:table_hrcs))'
```

or more simply:

```
' ... WHERE dummy MEMBER OF :table_hrcs'
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pLBiEL8r)

You may see a performance difference between the two with large amounts of data.

Also notice that the result array ends up with an empty last element.

Your example doesn't need to use a cursor and for-loop, you can bulk-collect directly into the target collection (which then doesn't need to be initialised, and doesn't have the empty element):

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_statement
BULK COLLECT INTO v_hrc_list
USING table_hrcs;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jLU6RPnf)

Comment: AAAARRR I'm so stupid :D, time to finish the package... thank you very much

Comment: @EnricoStöbe - also see the update for a version that doesn't use a loop.

Comment: maybe that helps, because apex is overburdened, thanks

i want to get all "HRCS" (like ids) and after collecting them i want to use them to get data.

Comment: mh i dont know... i use your "' ... WHERE dummy MEMBER OF :table_hrcs'" but now i get ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got AVATARS.HRC_LIST

i dont understand D:

Comment: It works in my fiddle, so maybe it's something else in the rest of the query statement that you didn't show? (In your fiddle you seem to be adding quotes - chr(39) - around things, which doesn't look necessary; I wonder if you're trying to put them into a collection within the select list or something? Maybe adapt my fiddle to show what you're doing to get that error...)

Comment: I added something for demonstration purposes https://dbfiddle.uk/LOut_O2G

first time i tried it without chr(39) and it dont work...

Comment: It doesn't work because you're trying to select the nonextistent column `hrc` form the dual table, as the error says. [It does basically work](https://dbfiddle.uk/5SE78Liu). Neither gets the ORA-00932 error.

Comment: its "solved" "=" instead of "member of"